# Want to print NULL if value is not present as awk output

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, awk

I am trying to print a tshark command output using awk below is my command:

```
tshark -r "test.pcap" -odiameter.tcp.ports:"1234" -R 'diameter.cmd.code == 272 and diameter.flags.request==0 and !tcp.analysis.retransmission and diameter.flags.T == 0' -Tpdml -Tfields -ediameter.Session-Id -ediameter.CC-Request-Type -ediameter.Result-Code -ediameter.Validity-Time  -ediameter.Unit-Quota-Threshold -ediameter-Value-Digits | awk '{print $1":"$2":"$3":"$4":"$5":"$6}'
```

Output:

```
xyz.test.com:1:2001:300:400:1234
```

If any of the six fields is empty i want to print " " or NULL value. For example if no output is coming for 4th field, i need output as below:

```
 xyz.test.com:1:2001::400:1234
```

But i am getting output as:

```
xyz.test.com:1:2001:400:1234:
```

Any suggestions will be very useful. I am open to use any linux command to get the expected output as mentioned.

Comment: By awk's definition NF = number of fields.  Pass it 5 fields, not 6, awk only sees five fields, thus (by definition) the LAST field is what's missing, regardless of what you say.  Pass it 4 fields, the last 2 fields are missing, etc.  To construct an order of 6 distinct fields, you have to evaluate each parameter (field). Host name is field 1, so run tshark to generate data for only field two and store it as a variable. Run tshark again to generate third field and store it's value in a different variable, then third run for field 4, and so on.  After 5 runs, print the 6 variables on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `tshark` parameters, I'm guessing you are trying to output 6 specific fields, and one of them is empty.
`tshark` by default uses a TAB character as separator, so the output will contain two consecutive TAB characters (indicating a missing value).
`awk` however, by default treats multiple tab/spaces as one field separator - thus it doesn't do what you expect.

The solution is to specify an single field-separator character in awk.

See example, the value "4" is missing from the simulated output:

```
$ printf "1\t2\t3\t\t5\t6\n"
1   2   3      5  6
```

By default, AWK treats the two tabs as one field-separator, resulting in:

```
$ printf "1\t2\t3\t\t5\t6\n" \
        | awk '{print $1":"$2":"$3":"$4":"$5":"$6}'
1:2:3:5:6:
```

What you want is likely this:

```
$ printf "1\t2\t3\t\t5\t6\n" \
      | awk -v FS='\t' '{print $1":"$2":"$3":"$4":"$5":"$6}'
1:2:3::5:6
```